# Can you fill readonly input fields with javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I was editing some code that was using ajax to fill out a form of user data based on user selection from a dropdown.  I didn't want users to edit the form fields, so I made the input fields readonly.  That created a non-deterministic issue where sometimes, mostly in IE9 and in quirks, the input three readonly input fields wouldn't populate.  But, I just had a user demonstrate it happen in chrome.

Does marking an input field readonly, protect it from all writes or just writes from user intervention?

Comment: You always can modify the DOM and its properties. `readonly` means only that the user can enter nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marking an input field readonly protects it just from user intervention. You can use scripts to change the value of the text labeling the input field. I kindly refer you to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_readonly if you wish to toy around with this concept some more.

Happy Coding!
RouteMapper